# How to export filename using loop index

Tags: indexing, sas, filenames

I am trying to export many files files where the exported filename reflects the iteration of a loop. Using the following code I the exported file is named "history_%i.dta" instead of the desired "history_0.dta", "history_1.dta", "history_2.dta", etc...

```
%macro exporthistory;
   %do i = 0 %to 9;
      proc export data = a.history&i outfile = "LOCATION/history_%i.dta";
      run;
   %end;
%mend exporthistory;

%exporthistory;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is exporting to Stata, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `history_%i.dta` to `history_&i..dta'.

```
%macro exporthistory;
   %do i = 0 %to 9;
     proc export data = a.history&i outfile = "LOCATION/history_&i..dta";
     run;
   %end;
%mend exporthistory;

%exporthistory;
```

Ampersand ("&") is the macro variable delimiter, as you correctly use earlier.  Also, you need a second period as `&i.` is the macro variable, and the second period is part of the filename.

Comment: It's probably worth emphasizing you've changed 'history_%i.dta' to 'history_&i.dta' - it took me a while to spot the '%' to '&' change.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much! I realize now how much of a novice question this was, but...I am a novice so it makes sense.